# Has this number triangle been studied?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, terminology

Let's make a number triangle like this.

$\sum 1 = x$

$ \sum \sum 1 = \sum x = 1/2 x + 1/2 x^2 $

$\sum \sum \sum 1 = \sum \sum x = \sum 1/2 x + 1/2 x^2 = 1/6 x^3 + 1/2 x^2 + 1/3 x $

...

So the triangle starts

1

1/2 1/2

1/6 1/2 1/3

...

So we have polynomials of degree n and we use the coëfficiënts for the triangle.

Has this number triangle been studied ?

Does it have a name ?

Comment: How does your triangle continue? You don't really show enough of it for the pattern to be clear.

Comment: They're related to Bernoulli numbers; recursive constructions for those polynomials are known. See [Faulhaber's formula (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula).

Comment: Sorry but there was chaos today in Belgium ... I slightly improved the OP @Henning

Comment: The edit just made me even more confused. I had speculated the terms of the left-hand-side might go $1$, $x$, $x^2$, $x^3$ (though just seeing $1$ and $x$ was not quite enough to be sure) ... but where on eath does $\frac12x+\frac12x^2$ suddenly come from? More lines or a generic description of line $n$, please.

Comment: Oh they just come from the line above ! I think the new edit is clear. I also gave An answer kinda. Although the question on how the fastest way to compute them remains.

Comment: It would be needed to add one more line of the array to decide, which type of matrix you're asking for. The Faulhaber matrix as well as the Stirlingmatrix (as in my answer) can be the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The matrix is likely this one:

$\qquad \qquad $ [image]

which is the matrix of unsigned Stirling numbers first kind, rowwise scaled by the reciprocal factorials.
Note, if the columns are *also* rescaled by the (original = non-recipocal) factorials (and the entries are alternating signed) then this becomes -if has infinite size- the Carleman-matrix **fS1F** for the function $\log(1+x)$ where the coefficients of the function's (and of their powers) formal power series are read column-wise, such that with a type of infinite vector $V(x)=[1,x,x^2,x^3,...]$ we have
$$ V(x) \cdot \text{fS1F} = V(\log(1+x)) \qquad \qquad \text{convergent for } |x|<1 $$
*(This relation to the generating function $\log(1+x)$ is also in the "Handbook of mathematical functions" of Abramowitz/Stegun, however without this explicite matrix-display)*

2. The matrix can also be this one:

But without having decoded the summation-noation it can also be the matrix of Faulhaber-polynomials (which I call "Gp" in my matrix-toolbox). It starts whith the same values in the first three rows:

$\qquad \qquad $ [image: gpmatrix]

After seeing the many sum-signs in the definition I rather believe it is this one meant and the matrix can be used to compute the "sums-of-like-powers" like in this geometric matrix-multiplication-scheme:

$\qquad \qquad $ [image: faulhaber]

Comment: What are the empty dots ? Are they 0 ?

Comment: Explain further plz

Comment: @mick: yes, in my essays I insert dots instead of zeros if the matrix is *triangular* and has thus ***systematic*** zeros (not just approximations)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out what i want is the stirling Numbers

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheFirstKind.html

, divided by the n th factorial.